# Razor Syntax clarification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx

In the above link…..

Code block Foreach

```
@{
    <h3>Team Members</h3> string[] teamMembers = {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert", "Nancy"};
    foreach (var person in teamMembers)
    {
        <p>@person</p>
    }
  }
```

why the h3 tag "Team Members" is not throwing the C# error saying not declared? This is inside the code block which says it is a C# code.
All the HTML tags are ignored inside the code block?

Similarly, why @ sign in @person? Is it not this code is also inside the code block?
Thank you,
Smith

Answer (score 2):

The @ symbol is the heart of the Razor syntax, the character that Razor uses to differentiate code from markup. The @ symbol marks a point at which the developer intends to switch from markup to code. In simple cases, no additional characters are needed to indicate when the code stops and the markup resumes. Razor’s intelligent parser determines which parts of the template are code and which are markup. What makes a valid code statement? Razor uses the following algorithm to find the end of a code statement once it reads the @ symbol trigger:

1. Read to the end of a valid identifier (i.e., a C# or VB keyword) or variable name.
2. If the next character is an opening bracket ( ( or [ )…

   a. Keep parsing until the corresponding closing bracket is located. Nested brackets
     are also tracked to avoid premature closing of a block.

   b. Loop back to #2.
3. If the next character is a . (period) and precedes a valid identifier, jump to #1.
4. Complete the code statement and continue processing the rest of the markup.

The reason the @person is there is to tell the Razor view engine that their is a transition between markup and code